# Compiling a Single NiFi Standard Processor

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I have an issue with the NiFi InvokeHTTP processor which requires me to make modifications to it. I am not trying to replace it but to create a fork which I can use alongside the original.

The easiest way I have found to do this is to clone the code, checkout the 1.10 tag and run `mvn clean install` in the `nifi/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors` directory.

However, the result of this is a JAR file named "nifi-standard-processors-1.10.0.jar". This contains ALL of the standard processors. Instead of this, I am looking to output each processor individually so I can upload *only* the modified InvokeHTTP processor to NiFi.

The only thing I can think of is to delete the source for the other processors individually which seems a little long-winded. I have had a look in `pom.xml` and cannot see anything obvious which would allow me to do this either.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Apologies if this is an easy question; I haven't used Java in over a decade and this is my first time using Maven.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code change one you can make by extending the processor rather than changing it at the source? If so, I'd recommend creating a custom processor which extends `InvokeHTTP` in its own Maven bundle (e.g. `nifi-harry-bundle`) which depends on `nifi-standard-processors`. This will allow you to use the functionality already provided, modify what you need to, and then only compile and build the new code, and copy/paste that NAR (NiFi Archive) directly into the NiFi `lib/` directory to consume it.

See [building custom processors](https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/02/04/custom-processors-for-apache-nifi) and [this presentation](https://github.com/alopresto/slides/tree/master/ioth_2019) for more details.

Comment: Hi Andy,

Thanks for the answer, extending the InvokeHTTP processor is a really good idea.

I've given it a shot but it can't seem to extend the InvokeHTTP class:

MyProcessor.java:[49,33] error: cannot inherit from final InvokeHTTP

Comment: Yes, the class is defined as `final`. I've opened [a Jira - NIFI-7482](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7482) to remove this, but in the meantime your options are:

1. Copy/paste the `InvokeHTTP` code into your custom processor and extend `AbstractProcessor` instead
2. Remove the `final` keyword in your `InvokeHTTP` definition and recompile the `nifi-standard-bundle` module so your component can extend it.

Comment: If you are ok using an unreleased NiFi version, I have merged the fix into `master` which you can build now as `1.12.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Wow, you modified the source code to provide me a solution! Thank you so much. Unfortunately I won't be able to use an unreleased version but will mark this as a correct answer as it's the easiest and most concise. I will probably switch to this once we catch up on versions. In the mean time I have used option 1 above. Thanks again!